# When did Ros receive the Lannister lion necklace from Tyrion?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In Game of Thrones Season 2 Episode 8 *The Prince of Winterfell*, Ros is shown to possess a Lannister lion necklace given to her by Tyrion.

> **Cersei**: Varys isn't the only one with who hears whispers. Really, a Lannister lion necklace. You need to hide your secret whores more carefully.

I checked the first episode and Ros is not wearing the necklace when she has her first scene with Tyrion. I do not recall when I first saw her wearing it. When did Tyrion give the necklace to her?

These are the times he could have given the necklace to her:

- In Winterfell on his way to the Wall
- In Winterfell on his way back from the Wall
- In King's Landing, ...

> particularly after the incident in Season 2 Episode 4 *Garden of Bones* where Joffrey made her abuse Daisy.

Comment: I like how you asked the question, and then answered almost immediately with detailed information and nicely cropped high quality stills from the tv series.

Comment: It's a question I had after watching the episode the other night. I researched and found the answer but I saw the question being asked elsewhere on the web so I thought I would try out the new self-answer checkbox and help anyone else that had the same question out.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

While the transaction is not depicted on screen, Ros is first shown wearing the lion necklace in Season 1 Episode 5 *The Wolf and the Lion*. In this episode, [Theon and Ros discuss](http://www.imdb.com/character/ch0251494/quotes) how she recently received the necklace from Tyrion.

[image: Ros in episode 105]

> **Ros**: You're not the only nobleman in my life, you know.
>
> **Theon Greyjoy**: Who, the Imp? I call him half a nobleman.
>
> **Ros**: Jealous?
>
> **Theon Greyjoy**: Why should I be jealous? Anyone with a few coppers in his pocket can own you for the night. What's a dwarf like down below? I've always wondered.
>
> **Ros**: Mmm, might surprise you.
>
> **Theon Greyjoy**: Mmm?
>
> **Ros**: He's good with his fingers, too. And his tongue.
>
> **Theon Greyjoy**: [Theon grabs Ros' necklace] Generous tipper. I guess gold is cheap for a Lannister.
>
> **Ros**: You ARE jealous.

Theon would likely have brought up the necklace before if the necklace had been given to her on Tyrion's trip to the Wall. One can conclude that Ros received the necklace from Tyrion offscreen during Season 1 Episode 4 *Cripples, Bastards, and Broken Things*.

> **Tyrion**: Spare me your false courtesies, Lord Stark. There's a brothel outside your walls. There I'll find a bed. Both of us can sleep easier.
>
> **Theon**: Can't resist some Northern ass? Do you like redheads? Ask for Ros.

Here's a better look at the necklace:

[image: Close up of the necklace]

Answer (score 0):

yes, she likely received it in episode four, season one after Rob Stark hinted Tyrion was not welcome to stay in the castle, before Tyrion presented blueprints for building a saddle for Bran. I suspect it was after Tyrion gave her a pearl necklace, which Ros would not accept for payment of her services.